# Configuring gitlab with TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, gitlab, continuous-delivery

I'm using GitLab CE 9.2.1 df00a75 and TeamCity 2017.1.1 (build 46654) and I need to build next:

1. When developer open merge request TeamCity should run ESlint and Jest tests and return to gitlab success or failure status.
2. When I accept merge request TeamCity should build project and deliver it.

What I achieved for now - tests run when open merge request and when I accept merge request tests also runs.

Part of VCS Root config. I think my problem is here →
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating GitLab with TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282548/integrating-gitlab-with-teamcity)

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto I saw this post. But can't achieve what I need according to right answer. By the way I configure my TC with two VCS roots and it works. But I'm not sure if it is a right way.

Comment: So what is your question? I see that everything works for you but I don't see what is the problem.
Anyway what you're doing is called "check out merge/pull request locally"  and described https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#checkout-merge-requests-locally